# Issues with many-to-many relation in EF core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to set up a many-to-many relationship between entity `Project` and entity `Resource`. I've created a relation entity: `ProjectResource`. I've set up the relation using fluent API like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectResource>()
    .HasKey(pr => new { pr.ProjectId, pr.ResourceId });

modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectResource>()
    .HasOne(pr => pr.Project)
    .WithMany(p => p.ProjectResources)
    .HasForeignKey(pr => pr.ProjectId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectResource>()
    .HasOne(pr => pr.Resource)
    .WithMany(r => r.ProjectResources)
    .HasForeignKey(pr => pr.ResourceId);
```

Here's a brief definition of my classes `Project` and `Resources` (**I'm only including that relationships**):

```
public class Resource
{
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

    public Guid? ManagerId { get; set; }
    public Resource Manager { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectResource> ProjectResources { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChangeLog> ChangeLogs { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Requirement> Requirements { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UseCase> UseCases { get; set; }  
}

public class Project
{
    public Guid ResponsibleId { get; set; }
    public Resource Responsible { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProjectResource> ProjectResources { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BusinessNeed> BusinessNeeds { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SuccessCriteria> SuccessCriterias { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Requirement> Requirements { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UseCase> UseCases { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChangeLog> ChangeLogs { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GlossaryWord> GlossaryWords { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectResource
{
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public Guid ResourceId { get; set; }
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
}
```

I've researched the problem, and I can't seem to find a solution. I've done just like the guide described [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration).

I'm getting the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProjectResources_Resources_ResourceId' on table 'ProjectResources' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do `Project` and `Resource` have a FK to a common entity (like `User` or something)?

Comment: @IvanStoev No they do not, but I'm not sure what this has to do with my issue?

Comment: Because it would create your *cycles or multiple cascade paths* issue. Imagine this structure: A -> B -> BC and A -> C -> BC where -> is one-to-many relationship with cascade delete. In your case, B is Project, C is Resource, BC is ProjectResource, and I was asking for A. Because B, C, BC cannot create cycle/multiple cascade path. There must be something else not shown here which is causing the problem. Create a clean new project with just code from the post and you'll see that it's not happening.

Comment: @IvanStoev Alright, I see what you mean. I've updated the SO. Could you perhaps explain further, if you see the issue in the above classes?

Comment: Yeah, I saw it. So instead of A, you have a second relationship between B and C, which is another way to create cycle. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the existing [required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#required-and-optional-relationships) (hence [cascade delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#cascade-delete)) one-to-many relationship between `Resource` and `Project`, expressed by `Responsible` / `ResponsibleId` properties in `Project`.

Here are the multiple cascade paths from `Resource` to `ProjectResource`:

```
Resource (Id) -> (ResponsibleId) Project (Id) -> (ProjectId) ProjectResource
Resource (Id) -> (ResourceId) ProjectResource
```

The only way to resolve multiple cascade paths is to break the cycle by turning off the cascade delete for at least one of the relationships and handle the deletion manually or via database trigger.

For this concrete model, probably the easiest would be to turn the delete cascade off for `Resource` -> `Project` relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
    .HasOne(p => p.Responsible)
    .WithMany()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: This does seem to resolve the issue but only if I set the delete behavior to `Restrict` on the relation between `ProjectResource` and the two relation tables: `modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectResource>().Hasone(pr => pr.Project).WithMany().HasForeignKey(pr => pr.ProjectId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)`

Comment: Indeed, it has to be set at the minimum places which break all cycles. I was looking only on those 3 entities (commented out the other relationships) and breaking at the place I mentioned in the answer worked for me. Btw, all that multiple cascade path issue is SqlServer specific. And may be also for some other database types. But some databases like Oracle handle it w/o any problem.